# Is there an equivalent of std::bind in javascript or node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stdbind

This is a long shot, but I was wondering if there is such a thing as the C++ std::bind in javascript or node.js? Here's the example where I felt the need for a bind:

```
var writeResponse = function(response, result) {
    response.write(JSON.stringify(result));
    response.end();
}


app.get('/sites', function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    dbaccess.exec(query, function(result) {
        res.write(JSON.stringify(result));
        res.end();
    });
});
```

Instead of passing the callback to dbaccesss.exec, I would like to pass a function pointer that takes one parameter. In C++ I would pass this:

```
std::bind(writeResponse, res)
```

This would result in a function that takes one parameter (the 'result' in my case), which I could pass instead of the anonymous callback.
Right now I am duplicating all that code in the anonymous function for every route in my express app.

Comment: [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it exists, I'd be more inclined to do it with a closure:

```
function writeResponse(res) {

    return function(result) {
        res.write(JSON.stringify(result));
        res.end();
    };
}
// and then...
dbaccess.exec(query, writeResponse(res));
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. I also find it more readable than using bind.

Answer (score 4):

If I understood well what you're trying to do, I ought to point to the 
[Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) method. It works like you described:

```
app.get('/sites', function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    dbaccess.exec(query, writeResponse.bind(null, res));
});
```

Comment: Indeed that's what I was looking for, although it looks like you should pass `undefined` rather than `null`?

Comment: It's more like a convention rather than a rule, but if you're passing the null object, you're kind of saying: that argument should be 'nothing'.

Answer (score 4):

Even though slightly different from the `bind` function as found in the `STL`, you can use `<function>.bind`, that is part of the prototype of a function in JavaScript.

The `bind` method returns a freshly created `function` object (do not forget that `function`s are first citizens in JavaScript and are built up starting from `Function` prototype) that accepts *N* minus *M* parameters (in JavaScript this is a weak constraint indeed, it will ever accept as many parameters as you pass it, but there are no guarantees that they will be used), where *N* is the original number of accepted parameters, while *M* are the bound ones.

The main difference is that `bind` accepts also as first argument a *scope* object which will be available from within the newly created function itself as the `this` reference, so you can literally change and inject the `this` reference during execution.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) you can find the documentation of `bind`.

As mentioned by someone, you can also rely on *closures* to get your target in almost all the cases where you can use *bind*.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if they're supported in NodeJS yet, but if so, you could also use fat arrow functions easily enough.

```
app.get('/sites', function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    dbaccess.exec(query, r => writeResponse(res, r))
});
```

They also retain the lexical `this` value, which is nice when needed.

It's roughly equivalent to this:

```
app.get('/sites', function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    dbaccess.exec(query, function(r) {
        return writeResponse(res, r);
    })
});
```

though this one has the `this` defined by `.exec()`.

Answer (score -1):

It does exist, there are two methods. [Call](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Function/call) and [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Function/apply) which are slightly different.

There is a [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Function/bind) method as well, but it does a different thing (changes the value of `this` when calling a function).

There is not such a thing as a 'function pointer' I think what you need here is [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying):

```
function currier(that, fn) {
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 2);

  return function() {
    return fn.apply(that, args);
  }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be what OP wants at all. And you can pass functions in JS, functions are objects and all objects are passed by reference.

Comment: "pass a function pointer that takes one parameter"  sounds to me like he wants to generate a function from a closure

Comment: @LuisSieira It mostly sounds like they don't _really_ understand the proper terminology to use when describing functions in JavaScript.

Comment: Clearly, but what I understand from the question is "I want to pass a function as a parameter, that will be executed later with some argument that hasn't been generated yet".

Here -> "This would result in a function that takes one parameter (the 'result' in my case), which I could pass instead of the anonymous callback"

Comment: You're missing out on the arguments passed to the function you're returning. You're going to need to join them with the bound `args`.